# Java ConcurrentHashMap and synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, race-condition, concurrenthashmap

Let's say that I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` of clients registered to a server (inside a class Server):

```
Map<ClientID, String> registeredClients = new ConcurrentHashMap<ClientID, String>();
```

In my registration method (inside the Server class) I have:

```
  public void synchronized register(ClientID client, String clientName) {
        if(!registeredClients.containsKey(client))
          registeredClients.put(client, clientName);
  }
```

And in any other methods of the server, I always check at the beginning that the client is registered (to be sure that he is eligible to use the method):

```
if(!registeredClients.containsKey(client))
  throw new UnknownClientException();
```

I have one server thread per client.

Have I to synchronize that check with something like this?

```
synchronized(registeredClients) {
  if(!registeredClients.containsKey(client))
    throw new UnknownClientException();
}
```

I think I should because theoretically the client could register after having passed the if guard and before throwing the exception (making the exception actually wrong).

I am not quite how much the `ConcurrentHashMap` helps programmers with synchronization issues.

Comment: There's an easy solution for your `register` method, but not for the rest.

Comment: putIfAbsent() ? I was thinking about that, but I think that behind the scenes it does something similar. I am more concerned with the 'check' problem. I think I have to synchronize multiple 'thread-safe operations'.

Comment: What happens if another thread unregisters the client right *after* the synchronized block exits?

Comment: What synchronization issues in particular are you trying to solve?

Comment: You *can* use `remove` to check if the key exists, and then just `put` again if it does. Don't know if you should though..

Comment: @immibis I am not sure if I can lock the whole ConcurrentHashMap (is it a good practice?, I am treating it like a simple HashMap)  which is supposed to be used concurrently.

Comment: @Kami You could lock it every time you use it, but then there's no benefit compared to just using a regular HashMap and locking it. What issues are you trying to solve?

Comment: @immibis Let's say concurrent registrations (but also unregistrations now that you mentioned it) after the first check. It seems like I should use a top-level synchronization, but this seems a bit too naive.

Comment: @Kami You want to make it so that a client can't register after the check but before the exception. What problem would that solve? After all, a client could also register after the exception is thrown, but before the catch block executes... and there's no way you can tell the difference, which means if one is wrong, then so is the other.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't have to synchonize the containsKey api if the Class is ConcurrentHashMap because as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) its operations are thread safe (You can read all the documentation in order to understand how concurrent access is managed).

I suggest you two modifications:

Change

`Map<ClientID, String> registeredClients = new ConcurrentHashMap<ClientID, String>();`

to

`ConcurrentMap<ClientID, String> registeredClients = new ConcurrentHashMap<ClientID, String>();`

because you want explicitly manage concurrent access in you code

After doing 1. you can use `registeredClients.putifAbsent(client, clientName);`

instead of

```
  if(!registeredClients.containsKey(client))
          registeredClients.put(client, clientName);
```

and avoid the `synchronized` keyword in the method signature

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, you can check with the following code:

```
registeredClients.computeIfAbsent(client, c -> {throw new UnknownClientException();});
```

The check if the key exists and the execution of the lambda are atomic. 
This requires UnknownClientException to be an unchecked exception.

For Java 7 I have no solution that is this simple.

Comment: Note: this is no better than `String name = registeredClients.get(client); if(name == null) throw new UnknownClientException();` (if you're not storing any null names in the table), or `if(!registeredClients.containsKey(client)) throw new UnknownClientException();` (if you don't need to actually get the client name).

Comment: wrong. you are using two statements to retrieve the name and to check it and so still have the race condition Kami wants to avoid. The code I wrote uses the computeIfAbsent method of the ConcurrentHashMap - that's what we are talking about here - and the Javadoc for that method states: _The entire method invocation is performed atomically, so the function is applied at most once per key._

Comment: Yes. But doing it atomically gains you nothing, because the client could still be registered right after your atomic call finishes (and throws an exception). End result is the same: the client is registered, but you threw an exception.